# Make errors also display in proper format and language

Tags: 7, webforms, i18n-l10n

I used webform and Internationalization. It works fine, but when error message are displayed, it shows in partial english and RTL and LTR is mixed up as shown in image.[image]

how do i correct it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either import translation for Webform, or keep in synch with [i10n](http://drupal.org/project/l10n_update).

If the string ('field is required') is not translated, you have to do it yourself in the translation interface `admin/config/regional/translate`.

Answer (score 5):

The required string for error messages is hardcoded into the Webform module, but it is run through the t() function (which translates known strings) like any other string. To translate it visit "admin/config/regional/translate/translate" and search for the string "!name field is required."